# What are Parking Windows in Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is a follow up question to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20584601/2530848.

I was under the impression that `Control` class doesn't implement finailzer which is true indeed, so leaked controls are leaked forever, not cleaned up during finalization.

[Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) gives some hint in comments section saying that it does, and some keyword `ParkingWindow`. I googled with that keyword, can't find any helpful resource about that.

Finally I found a class named `ParkingWindow` in `System.Windows.Forms.Application.ParkingWindow` through decompiler, I can't get to understand what is being done with that.

It looks like unparented windows will be parented to this parkingwindow and destroyed later at some point but not sure.

Question is what exactly is `ParkingWindow` and What it is used for?

Edit: How that is related to Control's Finalization or cleanup?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4083415/76337

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> and destroyed later at some point but not sure

That "not sure" is the crux of the problem.  This goes wrong very often with the window not getting destroyed at all.

Shawn Farka's blog post explains the original intent of the Parking Window well.  The expense of having to re-create the child windows was certainly on top of the list.  Not the only concern though, some types of child windows are *very* difficult to re-create accurately.  A TreeView is a good example, there's rather a lot of runtime state associate with it.  To do it accurately, you'd have to record the collapse state of every node.  That's painful and Winforms does not in fact do this.  When you re-assign, say, the CheckBoxes or StateImageList properties then you'll see this going wrong.

All and all, it is a nice trick but they went overboard with it.  A child control doesn't just (temporarily) end up on the Parking Window when the parent window gets recreated, it also is moved there when:

- you set its Parent property to null
- you use the parent's Controls collection's Remove/At() method
- you use the parent's Controls collection's Clear() method

Particularly the last two bullets are almost always *deadly* in a typical Winforms program.  They tend to be used when the programmer dynamically adds and removes controls at runtime.  Problem is, the control is re-hosted on the Parking Window but the programmer just forgets them there, losing the reference to the control.  And they will live there **forever**.  Until the user terminates the program because it turns into slow molasses from having thousands of windows created.  Or the program crashes with "Error creating window handle".  Which occurs when Windows gets sulky after the program has created 10,000 windows.

Instead, it is **required** to call the Dispose() method of the control.  Very unusual in .NET in general, calling Dispose() is always optional.  Not in the case of the Control class, the Parking Window keeps a reference on the control and thus prevents the finalizer from running.

Comment: Re-creating windows is hard and it's something that the VCL designers probably got wrong. There, controls do store away their state and try to restore it. I guess the WinForms people learned from the VCL experience.

Comment: Am not clear with this *Parking Window keeps a reference on the control and thus prevents the finalizer from running* I can't see Control class implements a destructor, What do you meant by finalizer here?

Comment: The finalizer is in the base class, Component.  It implements the disposable pattern so Dispose(bool) is the one that runs.  There's also plumbing in NativeWindow, which is wrapped.  It is ... convoluted.

Answer (score 7):

This is covered on this article by Shawn Burke from MS: [Windows Forms Parking Window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2007/06/20/flashback-windows-forms-parking-window.aspx).

> One of our goals with Windows Forms was try to smooth out as much of
>   the oddity of Win32 as we could.  And one of the principal oddities is
>   that of window handle (HWND) management and lifetime.  We certainly
>   didn't want the average user to need to worry about this stuff.  In
>   most cases, it was pretty easy.  You just gather up all of the state,
>   and then when you actually need to show the window, you do the
>   creation on demand, then you drive your state off the HWND instead of
>   your internal members.
>
> Well, this doesn't always work so well.  See, there are certain
>   properties of Win32 windows that you can't change once the window is
>   created.  Like the style of the border, for example.  So to allow a
>   user to change the border style after the window has been created, you
>   need to recreate the handle.  Which means you need to not only pull
>   all of the state out you want out of the existing one, but you need to
>   recreate it and push it back in.  Okay, that's not too hard.
>
> But what about the children?  Oh, fiddlesticks.  The kids.
>
> If the window you're modifying the border on has children, destroying
>   its handle will destroy the handles of all of its children as well. 
>   Then you need to recreate them, which is very expensive.  And
>   expensive is bad.
>
> Enter the Parking Window.  The Parking Window was our solution to this
>   problem.  It was somewhere that you could "park" HWNDs until you have
>   a fitting parent for them.  Think of it as Window Handle Foster Care,
>   but invisible.
>
> So in the case of a handle-recreate, we'd check to see if there were
>   any children.  If there were, we'd (if needed) create the Parking
>   Window, parent the children to that, recreate the parent's handle,
>   then move them back over.  Worked pretty well, though managing the
>   lifetime of the Parking Window did cause some problems...

Comment: Could you pls shed some light on how that's related to Control's finalization as Hans said? Am missing that here.

Comment: That's a different question. I don't know anything about that. You just asked *What exactly is `ParkingWindow` and what it is used for?*