# Why does removing a control from its parent trigger VisibilityChanged with Visible = true?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with some legacy code where I can not introduce big changes.
There is a control that has logic associated to the `OnVisibleChanged` event.

At one point during the Application Life-Cycle the control is removed from its parent, and when that happens the `OnVisibileChanged` event is fired two times. The first Time the control's visibility is `false`, and the second time is `true`.

Why is this happening? Why is the visibility changed being triggered the second time and with `Visible` being true?

**A simple way to reproduce the behavior I describe:**

Create a control:

```
class MyButton: Button
    {
        public MyButton()
        {
            Text = "Test";
        }

        protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnVisibleChanged(e);


            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Im now visible {0}", Visible));
        }        
    }
```

Use it in a form and remove it on the on click event of `otherButton`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private MyButton myButton = new MyButton();
        private GroupBox myGroupBox = new GroupBox();
        private Button otherButton = new Button();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            otherButton.Text = "Remove";            
            otherButton.Click += otherButton_Click;
            this.myGroupBox.Controls.Add(myButton);
            this.Controls.Add(otherButton);
            this.Controls.Add(myGroupBox);

        }

        void otherButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myGroupBox.Controls.Remove(myButton);
        }        
    }
```

After running this, if you click the `otherButton`, the Message will be shown twice, first the Visibility will be `false` and the second time will be `true`.

Comment: This program has a very nasty bug, a leak.  In 99% of all practical cases, it should be myButton.Dispose() instead.  The extra OnVisibleChanged() call is just a side-effect of the bug, it is trying to keep the button alive.  You can learn more about the "parking window" in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20585304/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant - I read the link you provided. So, If I understand correctly, if you mean to remove a control, on Winforms you should use Dispose and not remove from the Parent, because in reality it remains alive forever?! And I guess the VisibleChanged is being fired again because the control gets added to the ParkingWindow?

Comment: Yes and yes.  Calling the control's Dispose() method also removes it from the parent.  Using Remove and Clear is almost never correct, I can think of only one SO answer where I recommended using Remove, never once Clear.  That they are public methods was a design problem, not easy to avoid.

Comment: @HansPassant - In some of our scenarios, they didn't want the control to be disposed, they simply removed it from the parent and kept a reference to the control, for later use (adding them again). In that case the visibleChanged gets triggered twice. Is that also a bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

The cause is rooted somewhere in the native call to:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetParent(HandleRef hWnd, HandleRef hWndParent);
```

which is called in the `Control.Remove(...)` method. If you replace `Controls.Remove(myButton);` with `SetParent(myButton.Handle, IntPtr.Zero);` the same two events will fire.

My guess is that it is convenient to have the `VisibleChanged` event fire when the control is removed from its parent. However, the control was never explicitly hidden though. So the second call has to set the Visible property back to `true`. Otherwise if the button is added back to the control, it won't be visible.

Comment: I have the feeling is related to what Hans pointed out. The control is being added to the ParkingWindow and as you say, it was never explicitly hidden so the visibility is set to true.