# Add event to dynamically created button

Tags: vb.net

I have 4 picture boxes on my form. Whenever a new picture is selected the next available box populated and a button is created within that picture box.  I would like that button to be able to delete the image within that particular picturebox. I know how to create an event handler and then add the address to the button, what I do not know how to do is how to write the code so as to actually delete the assigned image on the assigned box.  Here is my code to load the pictures and create the button:

```
    Private Sub btnAddImage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddImage.Click, btnUploadImage.Click 4

        Dim btn As Button = New Button
        btn.Text = "Remove Image"


        'Procedure places the pictures in each empty picturebox in sequence
        ofdBrowsePictures.Multiselect = False
        ofdBrowsePictures.Title = "Select Image to Upload"
        ofdBrowsePictures.Filter = "Image Files |*.jpg*"

        If ofdBrowsePictures.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            'create array of each picture box and check if they are empty
            'Check if the picturebox contains a tag with the image path
            Dim PBs() As PictureBox = {picMainImage, picImage2, picImage3, picImage4}
            Dim nextPB = PBs.Where(Function(x) IsNothing(x.Image)).FirstOrDefault

            If Not IsNothing(nextPB) Then

                'if the box does not contain a image path, then place the picture on that box
                nextPB.ImageLocation = ofdBrowsePictures.FileName
                nextPB.Tag = nextPB.ImageLocation.ToString

                'add a button
                nextPB.Controls.Add(btn)

                'Create a border style on the image
                nextPB.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle

            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Set the location on the Button's `Tag` like you did for `nextPB` and then `File.Delete(buttonFromClickEvent.Tag)`. I may not  have understood exactly what you were asking for though...

Comment: Do you have more than one button displayed at a time? Could you have one button (created on the form as usual) which you dynamically move / show / hide as required? That might be simpler / safer than dynamically creating and deleting buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`what I do not know how to do is how to write the code so as to actually delete the assigned image on the assigned box`

I assume "delete image" means remove from the picture box, not delete from disk.

```
' what is 4???
Private Sub btnAddImage_Click(sender As Object, 
      e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddImage.Click, btnUploadImage.Click 4

    Dim btn As Button = New Button
    btn.Text = "Remove Image"

    ' bla bla bla set the imagelocation

    AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf RemoveImage_Click
    pb1.Controls.Add(btn)          ' btn.parent = this pb
End Sub

Private Sub RemoveImage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    ' clear image
    CType(btn.Parent, PictureBox).ImageLocation = ""

    RemoveHandler btn.Click, AddressOf RemoveImage_Click

    ' remove the control 
    pb1.Controls.Remove(btn)

    ' if you remove a control, dispose of it
    btn.Dispose()
End Sub
```

I am not sure I would invoke the dialog *before* checking for the next PB (nor would I create the new Button), since you seem to want to do nothing if there is no `nextPB` to play with.

For more information about Disposing of controls you Remove, see:

- [Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4083344)
- [What are Parking Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20585012)
- [Adding / removing controls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20584480)

Basically, forms dispose of controls when you close them.  If *you* Remove a control, the form no longer has a reference and cannot.  As a result, you should be disposing them.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these clear a picturebox image set with ImageLocation:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
PictureBox1.ImageLocation = ""
PictureBox1.ImageLocation = String.Empty
```